# Stacked Bar And Scatter Alignment

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart here: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/bx82z/

What I need is for the stacked bars and the scatter points to line up on each other based on the data X-element (county name in this case).
Getting the bars to stack was simple. But as you can see in the example the scatter points show up in the middle of the chart - not on the same x-value as the others.
I suppose I could create a category list (using the county names) but there may be cases where I do not have all 3 data elements for all counties - how to handle that scenario?
I did great the category axis and it is still doing the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/YckwW/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not defining the series correctly to achieve what you were wanting.  See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bx82z/5/) for what I think you are looking for.

In the cases where you are missing a piece of data for one of the countries you could always use **null**, which simply means there is nothing to display for that data point.  See [Missing Data Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/bx82z/7/) for an example.  It is case sensitive so make sure that null is all lower case.

Comment: The 'null' being lowercase was biting us. Fixed and good to go!

Comment: For my situation it needs to be all lowercase or it doesn't work.  I guess it depends on how you are implementing it.  Thanks for the feedback.